# Why do Python scripts on HDInsight fail with 'No module named numpy'?

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I've created a HDInsight cluster with [Apache Spark](http://spark.apache.org) using **Script Actions** as described in [Install and use Spark 1.0 on HDInsight Hadoop clusters](http://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-spark-install/):

> You can install Spark on any type of cluster in Hadoop on HDInsight using **Script Action** cluster customization. Script action lets you run scripts to customize a cluster, only when the cluster is being created. For more information, see [Customize HDInsight cluster using script action](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-customize-cluster).

I have ran a basic Python (word count sample) script that worked, but when I start a Python script that uses `NumPy` I get this importer error: `'No module named numpy'` raised on the nodes.

Why can't I import the package since NumPy was (supposed to be) installed out-of-the-box on a HDInsight cluster? Is there a way to install NumPy on the nodes? HDInsight doesn't allow you any access to the nodes.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Script Actions to apply custom packages to all the data nodes in an HDInsight cluster. The docs are at http://acom-sandbox.azurewebsites.net/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-hadoop-customize-cluster/

Roughly speaking what you want to do is create your cluster in PowerShell and include something like:

```
$config = Add-AzureHDInsightScriptAction -Config $config –Name MyScriptActionName –Uri http://uri.to/scriptaction.ps1 –Parameters MyScriptActionParameter -ClusterRoleCollection HeadNode,DataNode
```

The script at http://uri.to/scriptaction.ps1 can easily be stored on blob storage, and is run on the node types specified. That's script you would use to install any custom python (or other) packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom script as mentioned in the answers, however the below command worked for me in Hbase - Hdinsight Cluster. (It should work in Hadoop - Hdinsight Cluster as well.)

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```